# AS3, Flex Get Object of a Property

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, class, object, properties

my problem is to find out the object which owned my property... for example:

My Class :

```
public class MyClass{

     var myGroup:Group; //Spark Component
.....
}
```

Now, I add my Group to another UIComponent

Next step in Class XYZ I wan't to get my MyClass Object ... but I can only see the var myGroup

```
public class XYZ {

    ...
    public function getObject(group:Group):MyClass
    {
         return group.????;
}
...
    }
```

i know... its very freaky ;-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You’ll have to store a reference to `MyClass` in the group, because references usually don’t work like that (i.e. in both directions).

Comment: Maybe my answer for this question can be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051663/get-composed-movieclips-containing-parent-class-after-event

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class that extends `Group` and has one additional property that references the `MyClass` instance?

```
public class MyGroup extends Group {
  public var objectReference:MyClass;
  public function MyGroup(ref:MyClass) {
    this.objectReference = ref;
    super();
  }
}
```

and to retrieve the object:

```
public function getObject(group:MyGroup):MyClass
{
   return group.objectReference;
}
```

But I'm sure we could find a more elegant solution if you explained what are you trying to achieve in greater detail.

Comment: because ... i try to serialize my object to save it to hdd :-/ ... A Group can't be serialize :/